# F# using XML Type Provider to modify xml

Tags: f#, f#-data, fsharp.data.typeproviders

I need to process a bunch of XML documents. They are quite complex in their structure (i.e. loads of nodes), but the processing consists in changing the values for a few nodes and saving the file under a different name.

I am looking for a way to do that without having to reconstruct the output XML by explicitly instantiating all the types and passing all of the unchanged values in, but simply by copying them from the input. If the types generated automatically by the type provider were record types, I could simply create the output by `let output = { input with changedNode = myNewValue }`, but with the type provider I have to do `let output = MyXml.MyRoot(input.UnchangedNode1, input.UnchangedNode2, myNewValue, input.UnchangedNode3, ...)`. This is further complicated by my changed values being in some of the nested nodes, so I have quite a lot of fluff to pass in to get to it.

Comment: May I reccommend to **not** use Xml type provider and use some XSLT instead?

Some more info would possibly enlighten somewhat. To me it sounds like some kind of conditional search and replace, but it might of course just be me.

Comment: Lenses! You want lenses!

Comment: @MarkSeemann yes and no. but mostly yes. and more so no. so maybe. or ... ;-) It would actually be a "good" thing in such a case (if type providers allowed it, as Tomas 'cheatingly' explains). Until "write this new XML", which type providers still are no good at...

Comment: @HelgeReneUrholm, it might well be that XSLT is the productive way of solving this, however: 
- I have had horrendous experiences with XSLT, after working (back in the day) on an application engine whose logic was specified in XSLT transformations 
- it is not debuggable (not without Xml Spy or the likes)
- I'd much rather have my transformations written in code, I find it a lot clearer 
- functional programming seems the ideal tool for scenarios such as: get input -> crunch it -> output

Comment: In that sense, @MarkSeemann was on the right track and answered my unasked question, offering a suggestion which is a functional programming idiom

Comment: @user2916547 XSLT is (ok influenced by) functional programming... weirdly enough ;-)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out - I have never actually realised it! Still, as a general rule, I'd rather do transformations via code as I find it clearer and easier to read/work with/troubleshoot than XSLT.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The F# Data type providers were primarily designed to provide easy access when reading the data, so they do not have very good story for writing data (partly, the issue is that the underlying JSON representation is quite different than the underlying XML representation).

For XML, the type provider just wraps the standard `XElement` types, which happen to be mutable. This means that you can actually navigate to the elements using provided types, but then use the underlying LINQ to XML to mutate the value. For example:

```
type X = XmlProvider<"<foos><foo a=\"1\" /><foo a=\"2\" /></foos>">

// Change the 'a' attribute of all 'foo' nodes to 1234
let doc = X.GetSample()
for f in doc.Foos do
  f.XElement.SetAttributeValue(XName.Get "a", 1234)

// Prints the modified document    
doc.ToString()
```

This is likely not perfect - sometimes, you'll need to change the parent element (like here, the provided `f.A` property is not mutable), but it might do the trick. I don't know whether this is the best way of solving the problem in general, or whether something like XSLT might be easier - it probably depends on the concrete transformations.